# Applying a Chi-square test to a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am struggling to apply `chisq.test()` to a list of data frames. My list looks as follows:

```
> codons_list
$gct
  homo       all
1 1546 0.2857718
2 2991 0.7142282

$gcc
  homo       all
1 2181 0.2468482
2 2356 0.7531518
```

And is obviously much longer... So normally, I'd do `chisq.test(x=gct$homo, p=gct$all)`. When I tried to apply this to each element in the list using `lapply()` I got:

```
> chisq_list <- list()
> chisq_list <- lapply(codons_list, function(x) chisq.test(x[["homo"]], x[["all"]]))
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> chisq_list[[1]]

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  x[["homo"]] and x[["all"]]
X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

which is clearly a wrong result (the same for each element in the list); I failed to access the variables. Trying a for loop:

```
> chisq_list <- list()
> for (i in 1:length(codons_list)) {
+   chisq_list[names(codons_list[i])] <- 
+     chisq.test(x=codons_list[[i]]$homo, p=codons_list[[i]]$all) 
+     
+ }
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> chisq_list[[1]]
X-squared 
 67.19753
```

Looks better, but now I'm loosing most of the Chi2 test function's output (p-value etc.).

I would appreciate if somebody pointed out how to solve these problems. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#Data
codons_list <- list(gct = structure(list(homo = c(1546L, 2991L), all = c(0.2857718, 
0.7142282)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2")), 
    gcc = structure(list(homo = c(2181L, 2356L), all = c(0.2468482, 
    0.7531518)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"
    )))

#Just test
lapply(codons_list,function(x) chisq.test(x=x$homo, p=x$all))

$gct

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x$homo
X-squared = 67.198, df = 1, p-value = 2.456e-16


$gcc

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x$homo
X-squared = 1334.7, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Or if you want other element like p-vals:

```
#Just p vals
lapply(codons_list,function(x) chisq.test(x=x$homo, p=x$all)$p.value)

$gct
[1] 2.456177e-16

$gcc
[1] 3.222034e-292
```

Comment: So it seems the only problem with my code was the lack of x= and p= within chisq.test()

Comment: @carroll Great if this answer helped you to clarify the main issue of your question :) Let me know if really worked considering this answer!

Comment: It helped, thank you! I'd be still keen to know what is wrong with the loop though.

Comment: @carroll Awesome for sure you will master lists in `R`.